# ¿Como puedo hacer un efecto de brillo que se desplace al tener el cursos sobre un elemento hmtl?

Tags: html, css

Tengo una pagina pequeña que tiene unas tarjetas, pero quiero que cuando pases el cursor sobre ellas aparezca una estela de brillo que se desplace por la imagen.

Por si no se entendió el punto, es similar a lo que hace este sitio: https://u.gg/lol/champions

No tengo código actualmente de esto, y no se me vienen términos adecuados a la mente para realizar una búsqueda efectiva.

Answer (score 1):

Con la pseudo-clase `:hover` de CSS sobre el `div` de la tarjeta de la que quieras aplicar el efecto al pasar el cursor sobre el elemento.
Para el tema del 'brillo que se desplace por la imagen' tendrás que hacer una animación con CSS.
Tienes más información aquí:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:hover
- https://blog.hubspot.com/website/css-hover-animation

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)